# Python ical: get events for a day including recurring ones

Tags: python, datetime, icalendar, rfc5545

Is there an easy way to get a day's events from an ical file in Python?

For non-recurring, one day events I have used something like

```
from icalendar import Calendar
for event in Calendar.from_ical(ical).walk('vevent'):
    if edate > ref_ref_day_start and event.get('dtstart').dt < ref_day_end:
        # code here
```

But recurring events only occur in `walk` once.

I can see how having an infinite event iteration for repeating events without end could be a problem. But still there must be an easier way than calculating the repetitions by myself, right?

(I can't find much documentation. I read the icalendar test related to recurring events but it doesn't seem to do anything like this).

Comment: (This question isn't solved yet. I already tried a small bounty, which expired. Any solutions are still most welcome!)

Answer (score 2):

you can use pyICSParser.

It will take an ICS file and return the dates of recurring events in a list of datetime objects.

You need to specify the timewindow you want those events to be returned, as otherwise events recurring without an `UNTIL` or `COUNT` parameter would render an infinite list.

(disclaimer I'm the author of the package)

Comment: Hmm the idea is really nice but I can't get it to work. `pip` throws an `IOError` so I downloaded the source. I adapted the example to `mycal = iCalendar(); mycal.string_load(ical); print mycal.get_event_instances(start = '20150301', end = '20150315')` to try and make it work, but get a long exception trace.

Comment: Look like a nice package but the documentation is non-existant, and it can't read Google Calendar iCAL files. It fails with: `RFC5545 specifies: \'\xc2\xa73.6.1 specifies that \'The "VEVENT" calendar component cannot be nested within another calendar component.\', following line is not compliant \n line: 17 - END:VTIMEZONE'`

Answer (score 2):

You could use [python-recurring-ical-events](https://github.com/niccokunzmann/python-recurring-ical-events) in addition to `icalendar`.

```
pip install recurring-ical-events
```

Then, you can change your code to

```
from icalendar import Calendar
import recurring_ical_events
import datetime

today = datetime.date.today()

for event in recurring_ical_events.of(Calendar.from_ical(ical)).at(today):
    # code here for events of today
```

`icalendar` only parses the calendar file. This module works on event repetitions.

Comment: This is a good and extremely simple lib. `of()` also includes non-recurring events btw.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah.Instead of Ical Do it By  **gcalcli**

gcalcli is a Python application that allows you to access your Google Calendar(s) from a command line

**[1]: https://github.com/insanum/gcalcli**

Comment: I need the results in Python, sorry that was a little unclear. Can it do that (I'm not finding much) or only command line?